# How can I grant permissions to a user defined server role?

Tags: sql-server

I'm gIven the problem:

> Write a script that creates a user-defined role named VendorMaintenance in the AP database. Give update permissions to that role on the Vendors table and Select permission on the Invoice and InvoiceLineItems table. Assign the VendorMaintenance role to dbMaster.

I've looked through my textbook and came up with this incorrect solution.

```
USE AP
GO

CREATE SERVER ROLE VendorMaintenance
GO

GRANT UPDATE
ON Vendors
TO VendorMaintenance
GO

GRANT SELECT
ON Invoices 
TO VendorMaintenance
GO

GRANT SELECT
ON InvoiceLineItems 
TO VendorMaintenance
GO

ALTER SERVER ROLE VendorMaintenance ADD MEMBER dbMaster
GO
```

It says that `VendorMaintenance` isn't a user, and its not. but I need to grant these permissions to the role and then assign users to that role. Also is there a better way to write this?

Comment: for a database role, the syntax is : `CREATE ROLE...`  just remove the SERVER part from your script : `CREATE ROLE VendorMaintenance`    https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-role-transact-sql

Answer (score 0):

For a user-defined [database role](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-role-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), the syntax is as below. The role will be created in the current database context.

```
USE AP;
GO

CREATE ROLE VendorMaintenance;
GO
```

`CREATE SERVER ROLE` creates a user-defined [server role](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-server-role-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), which is used to grant server-scoped permissions rather than permissions on database-scoped objects.